# allow php file access protected folder by .htpasswd?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a site www.abc.domain.com, I protected it with .htpasswd. Now I have other www.domainname.com that contains a file callback.php, it requests to www.abc.domain.com. How do I write .htaccess file for both protecting www.abc.domain.com & allow file *.php **from outside** to access this secure folder?  I have many callback.php around the web, in any domain, any hosting.

Thank you

Comment: Where is outside? What have you tried so far? What is your concrete problem? Please show some code.

Comment: This is my code for callback.php. I know a solution that allow curl access protected folder, how do you combine with this code?

code at http://www.mediafire.com/?flrgnxa1uepl6hd

Answer (score 1):

Modify your callback scripts to access the domain with the credentials.

Another easy way would be to disable the protection for the IPs of the other hosts.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a careful look at [apache auth tutorials and documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/howto/auth.html).

You're probably going to use [`Satisfy Any`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/core.html#satisfy) and add list of known hosts.

You also may try using [`FilesMatch` or `DirectoryMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/sections.html) and build block like this:

```
<Directory ...>
   YourAuthConfig

   <FilesMatch  "/callback.php$">
       Allow from all
       Order allow,deny
       Satisfy any
   </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

*(I'm not sure whether this will work, please let me know in a comment)*

Comment: FileMatch does check the requested file not the file that requesting the content of the secured host.

And everyone could request the file, it wouldn't be secured!

Comment: @remy apache should allow you to add exception from AuthConfig based on filename/directory name, shouldn't it? That was what I'm trying to show. It may not work that way but I think it should. Is there any way we could make this approach work safely? Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it does. But as I understand the question, the file resisting on different hosts is called callback.php and not the file within the secured folder. The only save way would be to modify the requests to send the login credentials (fairly easy with curl).